# Назва обладнання - асИк чи асІк?

Tags: словотворення, іншомовні-слова, скорочення

Зараз дуже популярна тема майнінгу криптовалют, однак україномовних ресурсів про це мало, й усі вони не надто переймаються дотриманням мовних правил. На одному з [сайтів](https://pingblockchain.com/asik-majner-shho-zh-ce-take-i-docilnist-jogo/) знаходимо статтю:

> "Асик Майнер що ж це таке і доцільність його покупки сьогодні"

В тексті чимало мовних помилок, але вживання назви **асик** є формально вірним. Згідно з [правилом дев'ятки](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90), після с у запозиченому слові має стояти літера **и**, а не **і**.

Але не все так просто. **Асик** - абревіатура, в якій літера **и** має розкладатися у слово **інтегральна**. Чи не краще було б припустити, що задля збереження логіки словотвору там має стояти літера **і**, адже схема не **интегральна**, а **інтегральна**?

> ASIC (абревіатура від англ. Application-specific integrated circuit,
>   «інтегральна схема для специфічного застосування») — інтегральна
>   схема, спеціалізована для вирішення конкретного завдання.

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASIC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Правило девʼятки» не розповсюджується на абревіатури і похідні від них слова. А якщо *«асик»* — слово (відмінюване!), то розповсюджується.

На сайті лінгвістичного гуртка при кафедрі сучасної української мови Інституту філології Київського національного університету ім. Т.Г. Шевченка міститься [стаття](http://www.philology.kiev.ua/Lingur/art_17.htm), яка досить влучно розкриває проблему:

> “Виняток девʼятки” просто незастосовний у тих запозиченнях, де відбулася заміна `“е”` на `“и”`: *артіль, цісар, Лаврін* тощо.
>
> Неможливо його дотриматися і в загальних назвах, **похідних від абревіатур**: *стіфівець* (від “СТІФ”). Цілком природно, що і **складені слова** пишуться тільки з `“і”`: *безінерційний, безінформаційний, пресінформ, квазістаціонарний, зігнорувати, педінститут, будіндустрія.* (Але й тут є винятки: *дихлоретан, диграф.*)
>
> Незручність “девʼятки” виявляється ще й у тому, що нефахівцеві часто буває важко розділити слово на такі складові: *джіу-джітсу, “Пепсікола”, адідасівський, сідіром (CD-ROM), маріхуана*.

Далі автор вдається до політично-філософських аспектів. Не те, щоб я особисто погоджувався, але варто, принаймні, уваги.